# On a data frame, duplicate values if they are present on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, stringr

I need to write a column with values that are present on another table. Here is a minimal data example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("Jack", "Gina", "Helen", "John"))
data2 <- data.frame(col2 = c("Gina", "Ed", "John", "Sara"))
```

I need the code necessary to this following output:

```
   col1 col2
1  Jack   NA
2  Gina   Gina
3 Helen   NA
4  John   John
```

Where a new column named `data1$col2` is filled copying values form `data1$col1` but only if this value is present on `data2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can copy the column information of `col2` in `data2` to create a new column called `col1`, and then use `col1` as the key to conduct a join between `data1` and `data2`. `data3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

data3 <- data1 %>%
  left_join(data2 %>% mutate(col1 = col2), by = "col1")
data3
#    col1 col2
# 1  Jack <NA>
# 2  Gina Gina
# 3 Helen <NA>
# 4  John John
```

Answer (score 3):

```
transform(data1, col2 = as.character(data2$col2[match(data1$col1, data2$col2)]))
#   col1 col2
#1  Jack <NA>
#2  Gina Gina
#3 Helen <NA>
#4  John John
```

Answer (score 2):

A join option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[data2, col2 := col2, on = .(col1 = col2)]
data1
#   col1 col2
#1:  Jack <NA>
#2:  Gina Gina
#3: Helen <NA>
#4:  John John
```